# Echo a hierarchical list of post data from custom fields

Tags: php, query, wpdb

I have a custom post type 'locations', with custom fields 'State', 'City', 'Address', and 'Phone'.

I would like to query these fields in an organized list. Let's say I have these three posts:

> City: Los Angeles; State: California; Address: 123 Main St.; Phone:
>   888-111-2222
>
> City: San Jose; State: California; Address: 55 1st St.; Phone:
>   888-333-4444
>
> City: Brooklyn; State: New York; Address: 9 25th St.; Phone:
>   888-555-4848

Should display like this:

> - California
>
>   - Los Angeles
>
>     - 123 Main St.
>     - 888-111-2222
>   - San Jose
>
>     - 55 1st St.
>     - 888-333-4444
> - New York
>
>   - Brooklyn
>
>     - 9 25th St.
>     - 888-555-4848

So far, I am using this code to grab the states in a list and it is working:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT meta_value, COUNT(post_id) as count FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'state' GROUP BY meta_value ORDER BY meta_value;";
$states = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
foreach( $states as $state ) :
echo'<li>'; echo $state->meta_value; echo '</li>';
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

But this is of course only displaying:

> - California
> - New York

What I'm trying to figure out is how to query the rest of the data I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem with querying just the meta table is that you don't know the status of the posts they're attached to- you'll get meta for posts in the trash for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue using this guide: http://www.tomoro.com.au/blog/sort-and-group-posts-by-custom-field-with-unique-headings-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

A little example, based on get_posts and get_post_meta.

```
$locations = get_posts(
    array('post_type' => 'locations',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($locations as $location) {
  $location_city = get_post_meta($location->ID, 'city', true);
  $location_state = get_post_meta($location->ID, 'state', true);
  $location_address = get_post_meta($location->ID, 'address', true);

  echo '<li>' . $location_city;
  echo '<li>' . $location_state . '</li>';
  echo '<li>' . $location_address . '</li>';
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

You'll need to adapt $args array in the get_posts to order by special value. With this way you loop through posts and retrieve their custom fields with get_post_meta.

Edit:
You can add a meta_query array in the arguments for the query, to get or order.
[Custom field in WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it's missing the critical aspect, which is that I need to organize the locations by one of the custom fields. First the list of states needs to get called, and then all cities which have that state in the custom field are listed under that state.

Comment: As i told you, you'll need to modify and adjust the array in get_posts(), using a meta_query array which can be nested and order as you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I tried to look into meta_query but didn't seem to be able to apply it to my needs. Ended up finding the solution online